# How to restrict non logged in users from accessing the api data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here are the `permissions.py`

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS


class ReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS
```

How to modify this so only logged in users can access the data

Comment: You should import and set `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `permissions.py` to

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, IsAuthenticated, SAFE_METHODS




class ReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] #new

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in SAFE_METHODS
```

This will do the rest what you wanted